# Socket.io disconnect with forever nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, forever

I'm using [**socket.io**](http://socket.io/) in [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) *([node.js](https://nodejs.org/))*.

I want to write some field in BBDD when the last socket from one user is disconnect. I'm using a code like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            var numberOfSocketClient = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.request.user.id] || {}).length;
            if(numberOfSocketsClient == 0)
                 //Write in BBDD some field
    });
});
```

- In **localhost**, with `grunt` command, is working well and writes in BBDD
  when the user disconnects all his socket channels.
- In **AWS** with `node server.js`command is working well and writes in BBDD
  when the user disconnects all his socket channels.
- In **AWS** with `forever start server.js`command, **IS NOT WORKING**. Not enters inside `socket.on('disconnect')` callback.

In production mode I need to use the `forever` command and I want to fix this problem.

- Why this is happen?
- How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet. If you found tell me please :)

Comment: Aral, my problem was that i was doing `sudo forever start server.js`, and it wouldn't pass environment variables. Now I'm doing `sudo -E forever start server.js` and my problem is solved